I try to extract data from txt file
I have a large data file . The data which I would to extract in format
GROUP NUMBER   1
N        BIRTH        CODE        TEST 1      TEST 2       TEST 3       TOTAL          ID  
1    28-4-1986    0000000001  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  1019892555  
2    29-4-1986    0000000001  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  1019892555  
3    28-4-1986    0000000001  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  1019892555

TOTAL=

GROUP NUMBER   2
N        BIRTH        CODE        TEST 1      TEST 2       TEST 3       TOTAL          ID  
1    28-4-1986    0000000001  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  1019892555  
2    29-4-1986    0000000001  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  1019892555  
3    28-4-1986    0000000001  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  1019892555

TOTAL=

GROUP NUMBER   3
N        BIRTH        CODE        TEST 1      TEST 2       TEST 3       TOTAL          ID  
1    28-4-1986    0000000001  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  1019892555  
2    29-4-1986    0000000001  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  1019892555  
3    28-4-1986    0000000001  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  1019892555

TOTAL=

WHERE GROUP NUMBER CHANGE FROM 1 TO 1000

 \# in real it is up to 10000000 so it is difficult to defined each group number

I want to extract into text file the total column for group number 1 51 101 151 201 251 301 351 401 451 501 551 601 651 701 751 801 851 901 951.
I write code:
with open('data.txt') as infile, open('total.txt', 'w') as outfile:     
copy = False     
for line in infile:        
if line.startswith("GROUP NUMBER   1"):             
copy = True        
elif line.startswith("TOTAL"):             
copy = False        
elif line.startswith("GROUP NUMBER  51"):             
copy = True        
elif line.startswith("TOTAL"):             
copy = False        
elif line.startswith("ZONE NUMBER  101"):             
copy = True        
elif line.startswith("TOTAL"):             
copy = False 
#UNTIL REACH 951            
continue             
outfile.write(line)             
continue        
elif copy:             
outfile.write(line) 

my questions
1- can I let the group number change automatic by do?
2- can I extract only the column total not all data in between ?
thanks
